# pandas DataFrame (easy?) manipulation

Tags: python, pandas

```
pd.DataFrame({'id': ['id1', 'id1', 'id2', 'id2'],
                  'value': ['1', '2', '10', '20'],
                  'index': ['day1', 'day2', 'day1', 'day2']})
```

how can I transform this data correctly (and concisely)  with pandas that it results in:

```
    |   id1  |  id2

day1 :   1   |   10

day2 :   2   |   20
```

Maybe something with groupby but without aggregation, I dont know what to google, can you help me?
thank you very much

Comment: Does `df.pivot('index', 'id', 'value')` give you what you want?

Comment: thanks! so easy if you know it ^^ I still have to learn a lot

Comment: Dont get discouraged. Keep learning. Ask and dont just take answers.Look into the answers and read. Pandas and python have good documentation. Tutorials are the other thing too. Keep coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [pandas pivot](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html). It reshapes datframe based on the input conditions

```
 pd.pivot_table(df, index=['index'], columns=['id'],values='value').reset_index()
```

Just remember to set `value` to float or integer